# storing value in java server pages using Eclipse platform

Tags: eclipse, jsp, variables, store, default-value

i wanna store a static variable in the jsp file in Eclipse platform.On running each time i should get back the value from that variable.im new to jsp,pls do ellabarate the concept guys

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<%! int visitors = 0; %>
```

Comment: ! makes the scope static.